# array pattern from parent to sub row

Tags: php, arrays

My array is:

```
[
 "0"=>["id"=>111,"name"=>"abc","value"=>"s1"],
 "1"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"s2"],
 "2"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"s3"],
 "3"=>["id"=>"222","name"=>"xyz","value"=>"a1"],
 "4"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"a2"],
 "5"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"a3"],
 "6"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"a4"]
];
```

I need this format of my array:

```
[
   "0"=>["id"=>111,"name"=>"abc","value"=>["s1","s2","s3"],
   "1"=>["id"=>"222","name"=>"xyz","value"=>"a1","a2","a3","a4"],
];
```

Comment: Hi Sonia! Thanks for clearly showing your problem. Could you also post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding, what you want doesn’t make sense in that you’re trying to keep the array structure of value while removing the enclosing brackets. If you want to flatten your array you could stringify that value array into a JSON string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e441640e8d1a40bf2b88652a0232bf855a5fd44)

```
<?php

$arr = [
 "0"=>["id"=>111,"name"=>"abc","value"=>"s1"],
 "1"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"s2"],
 "2"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"s3"],
 "3"=>["id"=>"222","name"=>"xyz","value"=>"a1"],
 "4"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"a2"],
 "5"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"a3"],
 "6"=>["id"=>"","name"=>"","value"=>"a4"]
];

// An array to store the results
$results = [];

// Store the index of the current results element
// Start with -1 because going to begin with an increment
$index = -1;

foreach ($arr as $element) {
    if ($element["id"] !== "") { // If contains an ID field

        // begin with increment; initial value must be -1
        $index++;

        // Create new results element
        $results[$index] = [ 
            "id" => $element["id"],
            "name" => $element["name"],
            "value" => [
                $element["value"],
            ],
        ];
    }
    else { // If does not contain an ID field

        // Add another "value" to existing element at $index
        $results[$index]["value"][] = $element["value"];
    }
}

var_dump(json_encode($results));
```

Output:

```
[
     {"id":111,"name":"abc","value":["s1","s2","s3"]},
     {"id":"222","name":"xyz","value":["a1","a2","a3","a4"]}
]
```